# Логика действий постинкрементов

Tags: java

Помогите разобраться в логике действий. Что левый оперант всегда сохраняется отдельно и потом возвращается более менее осознал в некоторых примерах что нашел, но в этом не получается понять ход действий. Пробовал прогнать через инспекцию в Intelij и она сообщает что второе инкрементирование вообще не срабатывает, а почему не понимаю.

```
int x = 5;
x = x++ + x++;
System.out.println(x);
```

Программа выводит:

```
 11
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Постинкремент сначала вернет значение переменной, а после увеличит ее значение на `1`.

Поэтому это выражение

```
int x = 5;
x = x++ + x++;
```

можно описать как:

```
x = 5 + 6;
```

Первый `x++`, вернет `5`, но увеличив значение до `6`, поэтому второй `x++` вернет `6`, увеличив значение до `7`.

Однако, у нас уже есть присваивание `x`, поэтому туда запишется сумма -- `11`

Проверяем:

```
int x = 5;
int y = x++ + x++;
System.out.println(y + " - " + x);
// 11 - 7
```

Comment: Т.е. последним действием выражения будет "x = 5+6" которое сотрет "x=7".
Я правильно понял?

Comment: @DenisKukharenko, да. Пример с `int y` это и показывает :)

Comment: Теперь точно понял. Спасибо за объяснение.

Answer (score 0):

запись x++ (post increment) инкррементирует значение после сложения

```
x = 5;
y = x++ + x++;
y = 5   + 6;
x = 7;
```

если хотите инкрементировать до, используйте ++x (pre increment)

```
x = 5
y = ++x + ++x;
y = 6   + 7;
x = 7
```

или так

```
x = 5
y = ++x + x++;
y = 6   + 6;
x = 7;
```

**++a**

```
a = a + 1;
return a;
```

**a++**

```
temp = a;
a = a + 1;
return temp;
```